# Column in regex matching

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to do something like this in postgresql 9.1

```
select name from persons where 'Usher is a great singer' ~ concat('\\m',name,'\\M');
```

Where the column "name" has the following values: Usher, Micheal, John Smith. But it always return an empty result.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Why are you escaping the \ ? How do you use this ?

Comment: change `~ concat('\\m',name,'\\M') to concat('\m',name,'\M')`

Comment: I'm not sure of the real use case but you might be interested in this : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-controls.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing this is a query, not a string literal in a specific language adding constraints, you don't have to escape the `\` :

```
select name from persons where
   'Usher is a great singer' ~ concat('\m',name,'\M');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting `Usher is a great singer` from `persons` shouldn't you select a table column value?

Comment: the `~` in postgres is a regular expression operator

Answer (score 0):

- i think the given below will also works

> select name from persons where 'Usher  is a great singer' ~
>   concat(name);